# UIImage not retrieving From NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

In my application I grab an image from a picker and then try to display it in a separate view.

In my MainViewController.m I have

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {

    self.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image) forKey:@"imageKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    PublishViewController *publish = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Publish"];
    [self presentViewController:publish animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
}
```

I then try to retrieve the image in my PublishViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSData *imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"imageKey"];
UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:userImage];
}
```

The image does not show though. Any reason why?

Comment: Did you check if self.image is null or imageData is null or both?

Comment: How specifically? @HermannKlecker

Comment: Using `NSUserDefaults` for this is not appropriate. Why not add a `UIImage` property to your `PublishViewController` and set the property from your main view controller? There is no need to write the image to the user defaults just so you can pass it from one controller to another.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is neither a tool for inter-object communication nor is it capable of siting big binary data. just don't do what you intent to do. as rmaddy said: pass it with an property.

Comment: @asdasdasd: this is objective-c basic. refer to the doc of your choice. or search stack overflow for it. it has been answered hundreds, if not thousands of times.

Comment: NSUserdefaults is for small stuff: strings, arrays, dictionaries and so on. It's basically to store user settings, but to to store images. It's a Plist and it can only store plist-kind of objects. I don't know if what you are trying to store qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `-viewDidLoad` in PublishViewController.m is called before the completion block in `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` and the NSData has not been saved in NSUserDefaults, yet.
You could put the code to load `self.image` in PublishViewController.m into `-ViewDidAppear`.
Now that being said I agree with the commenters that NSUserDefaults may not be the best place to store the image data.

Comment: The data for the image is stored in `NSUserDefaults` as soon as the call to `setObject:forKey:` is made. There is no timing issue here.

Comment: In the ViewController lifecycle, perhaps `-viewDidLoad` was already called for PublishViewController when MainViewController is presenting it (when the ImagePicker is dismissed?)

Comment: Since the view controller is created after setting the image in `NSUserDefaults`, it is impossible that the `viewDidLoad` method is being called after the image is set.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `NSUserDefaults`, you are better using `NSFileManager` to save the image.

Within the pickerController Delegate methods of your `MainViewController.m`, place the following code -

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

    //This code will save your image so you can retrieve it anywhere else within the app.
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourImageName.jpg"];
    [manager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
}
```

Where you can save the image name to whatever you like

Then within the `viewDidLoad` of your `PublishViewController.m` place this code to retrieve the image -

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourImageName.jpg"];
    UIImage *retrievedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    self.yourImageView.image = retrievedImage;
}
```

Place a `UIImageView` on the view controller of your `PublishViewController`, which I've called `yourImageView`, for this example.

This will work for what you're looking for, hope it helps.

Thanks, Jim.